# windows WaitForMultipleObjects / MsgWaitForMultipleObjects difference

Tags: windows, winapi, events, waitforsingleobject

I'm trying to understand the difference between `MsgWaitFor` and `WaitFor` functions.

1) I understand that the `MsgWaitFor` is running under a message loop, while the `WaitFor` does not?
2) Does the `MsgWaitFor` functions is better for an application that need to receive a sequence of events in a row? Does Windows queues the messages, so the application won't miss any events?
Say application wants to receive event `A` and `B` which happens frequently. 
The application will open a thread:

```
while (1) {
  ret = WaitForMultipleObjects(...); // wait for events A and B
  if (ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
    process_event();
  }
}
```

The question is, when the thread is busy with processing, meaning it is currently not blocked by `WaitForMultipleObjects`. How can the thread avoid missing the events until it goes back to waiting?

Comment: `MsgWaitForSingleObject` does not exist. If you want to find out, what `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` does, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjects) is the best place to get that.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the question. I'm still asking what is the difference between them

Comment: They do the same thing, except that `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` adds its own event object to the list of handles to wait for, based on the `dwWakeMask` you supply.

Comment: My question is about an event sequence. I want to know if a processing thread can miss events when using these `WaitFor` functions. Or does Windows queue them for the application.

Comment: @user3599803 - not exist any wait object (not only event) sequence. api wait for all or for any objects is set to signaled

Comment: *How can the thread avoid missing the events until it goes back to waiting?* - nothing will be missed. because anyway object will be in signal state

Comment: @RbMm But what you're describing seems to only fit for one event of a kind. I need some way to receive many events of the same type in a row.
I know that calling SetEvent and then ResetEvent can lead to event being missed

Comment: no, what i describe is exactly and for any count of objects (not event only!). and i not understand about what you ask at all

Comment: you can wait for all object or for first (any) object signaled

Comment: @user3599803 **Message** has queue and the queue has a length ([10,000 posted messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea?redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks)). So when processing messages too slow, the `PostMessage` may fails with `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA`. But for receiver side, you **will not miss** messages and you can handle queued messages one by one.

Comment: @user3599803 **Event object** has no queue and it has two state: `signaled` and `nonsignaled`. [Setting an event that is already set has no effect.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setevent#remarks) So if this is a manual-reset event object, it remains `signaled` until it is set explicitly to the `nonsignaled` state by the `ResetEvent` function. There may be a miss at setting side instead of checking side. In this case, if using a [semaphore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-releasesemaphore) can meet your goal?

Comment: Thank you @RitaHan-MSFT, this is the answer I needed, semaphore can work but seems less convenient. I just wanted to make sure that `MsgWaitFor` won't miss on the receiver side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to understand the difference between MsgWaitFor and WaitFor
>   functions.

The main difference is `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`/`MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` can wait for messages (in message queue) in addition to the following object types:

- Change notification
- Console input
- Event
- Memory resource notification
- Mutex
- Process
- Semaphore
- Thread
- Waitable timer

So if you have a thread that creates windows, use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` or `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`, rather than `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx`.

> The question is, when the thread is busy with processing, meaning it
>   is currently not blocked by WaitForMultipleObjects. How can the thread
>   avoid missing the events until it goes back to waiting?

**Message** has queue and the queue has a length ([10,000 posted messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea?redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks)). So when processing messages too slow, the [`PostMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea?redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks) may fails with `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA`. But for receiver side, you will not miss messages and you can handle queued messages one by one.

**Event** object has no queue and it has two state: `signaled` and `nonsignaled`. [Setting an event that is already set has no effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setevent#remarks). So if this is a manual-reset event object, it remains `signaled` until it is set explicitly to the `nonsignaled` state by the [`ResetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-resetevent) function. There may be a miss at setting side instead of checking side.

Answer (score 0):

both [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects[Ex]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjectsex) and [`WaitForMultipleObjects[Ex]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjectsex) internal call the same api - [`KeWaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-kewaitformultipleobjects)

different in - `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects[Ex]` add event (in front, at 0 index) to array of object handles. because `KeWaitForMultipleObjects` have restriction of maximum number of objects to `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`, the same restriction have and `WaitForMultipleObjects[Ex]` and `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS - 1` for `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects[Ex]` (because used additional +1 event object)

exist only 2 `WAIT_TYPE` - either `WaitAll`, indicating that all of the specified objects must attain a signaled state before the wait is satisfied; or `WaitAny`, indicating that any one of the objects must attain a signaled state before the wait is satisfied.

when we wait for object to be signaled - not important will be object in signal state before or after we begin wait for it. we not miss signal state anyway. of course if we manually not reset object to not signal state again. but this already question of program logic and not related to wait api

> sequence of events in a row

not exist any sequence here. every object can be in 2 states (signaled or not) and we can wait for all or any objects in signaled state. if you wait for any - which object first will be signaled depend from concrete situation.

> Does Windows queues the messages, so the application won't miss any
>   events?

no any messages at all. exist only objects with `DISPATCHER_HEADER` (look in *wdm.h*) inside it. wait api check `SignalState` of `DISPATCHER_HEADER` and if it set already - return control (if we wait for single object or any object of course). if not - insert thread to `WaitListHead` (this is double linked list, where can be multiple threads, which wait for this object, and begin from win8 - *WaitCompletionPacket's* objects. when object go to signal state (`SignalState` set to non zero). system wake first (*SynchronizationEvent*) or all (*NotificationEvent*, other object types) waiting threads in `WaitListHead` (again based on waitall or wait any). in case *WaitCompletionPacket* - it queued to iocp

so again - we nothing miss (if not reset object by self again)